# JSch - How to capture stream from remote server using PortForwarding L?

Tags: java, jsch, portforwarding, bufferedinputstream

I tried to use InputStream and Buffer[], also BufferedReader, also PipedInputStream. For all cases i got null:

```
        sessionB = jSch.getSession(username, "localhost", forwardedPort);
        sessionB.connect();

          if(sessionB.isConnected()) {
             System.out.println("Connected host B!");

             channel = (ChannelExec) sessionB.openChannel("exec");   

             br = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream())); 
             ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("command");
             ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

             channel.connect();

             if(channel.isConnected()) {

                System.out.println("Channel is connected!");
            }

             String line;

                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    }
```

### And console output:

### Connected host A! Connected host B! Channel is connected!

Problem: I got nothing printed (System.out.println(line);)

There is a way to get that stream from exec channel over portforwarding ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, assuming the rest of the code, which you didn't show us, is reasonable. We need [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

get/setInputStream and get/setOutputStream only concern the standard input/output of the command, nothing to do with port forwarding.
The port forwarding is done through two functions setPortForwardingL and setPortForwardingR.

You should have something like that in your code.

```
int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
```

As always, there is very few documentation on JSCH but a lot of [detailed examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples) for [L forwarding](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java.html) and [R forwarding](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingR.java.html)

The port forwarding is done on the session so I'm not sure you also need an active connection. But if you do, you should consider opening a 'shell' connection instead of an 'exec'. Then you wouldn't have to run a useless command just to maintain the connection.

PS: Some code is missing so it's difficult to say something precise on the example given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I solved it using Pipes, i share what i did:

```
  PipedInputStream en = new PipedInputStream();
  pin = new PipedOutputStream((PipedInputStream) en);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((PipedInputStream) 
  channel.getInputStream()));

  channel.connect(5*1000);     


  String received=null;
  while((received=br.readLine())!=null) {
      System.out.println(received);
  }
```

Comment: I still don't get your code. From what I read your variable 'pin' is not used and what you do is just collecting your command output with a buffered reader.

Comment: I thing the casting of channel.getInputStream() in PipedInputStream is useless.

Comment: First buffer input, then read like this: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((received=br.readLine())!=null) {sb.append(received+"\n"); // I agree with you, but marks an error without that casting